# Prolog get items between the items supplied from a list PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to build a list function in prolog which will hopefully do the following;

```
split(1, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4]). [2, 3]
split(2, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]). [3]
```

That is it will put all the items in a list which appear in between the two value provided.

What have I tried;

```
split(Start, Finish, List) :- append(List, _, [Start|Xs]),
                              append([Finish|Xs], _, List).
```

I can just never seem to get it working! I am new to prolog so please be relatively kind!!

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ok so I have a solution and would like to know if it could be improved. The solution is below,

```
% Split a list at a specified index
split(List, Index, Front, Back) :-
  length(Front, Index),
  append(Front, Back, List).

% Get list items inbetween members
inbetween(List, From, To, Result) :- 
  nth1(FromI, List, From),
  nth0(ToI, List, To),
  split(List, FromI, _, List1),
  split(List, ToI, _, List2),
  subtract(List1, List2, Result).
```

As you can see I followed the advice in the comments and tweaked it a little. Are there any improvements to this?

Thanks, (Could it even be possible in one predicate?)

**EXAMPLE**

```
 inbetween([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2, 5, Result). % [3,4]
 inbetween([a,b,c,d,e,f], a, e, Result). % [b,c,d]
```

Comment: Looks like you're not thinking carefully enough about what `append/3` does. `append(A, B, C)` says that `C` is `B` appended to the end of `A`. When you say, `append(List, _, [Start|Xs])`, that says that `[Start|Xs]` is *something* (`_`) appended to `List`. In other words, if `List` isn't empty, then it will start with `Start`, which already sounds wrong based upon what you're trying to achieve. Using `append/3`, though, will be tricky because you can have termination issues. You also need a fourth argument if you want to see the results.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will have another go and re-edit the question when I have made progress. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's an idea: start with `split(X, Y, List, Result) :- split_front(X, List, R1), split_back(Y, R1, Result).` which reduces it to figuring out `split_front` (which says that `R1` is everything in `List` after an `X`) and `split_back`. (which says that `Result` is everything in `R1` before a `Y`). It's just one of a couple of different approaches one could take, but maybe that will make it easier to think through.

Comment: Hey, I think I did it, I edited question, what you think?

Comment: Oh so the first to arguments are an *index* not the name of elements? I didn't realize that since your element names in the first example also happen to be the indices. Maybe I'm still confused. Can you show an example using letters as list members?

Comment: It doesn't really matter it can be both, I'll edit :)

Comment: I know it can be both. It's just hard for me to tell whether you're referring to an index or an element when the elements are numbers.

Comment: Without your help I wouldn't have been able to do it so thanks. And extra thanks for not giving the solution but a very helpful hint.

Comment: OK your example is what I originally thought you wanted to do. Thanks. :) If you want to explore a method that doesn't use `append/3` or `nth0/3` or `nth1/3`, you could go back and try my idea of the `split_front` and `split_back` I did it with just a few lines of recursive predicate. And here's a trick question: what should the result (or results) of `inbetween([a,b,c,a,d,e,b,f], a, b, R)` be?

Comment: I did find a bug in your solution if you allow repeated elements: `inbetween([a,b,c,d,e,c], a, c, L)` will yield `L = [b]` correctly but also gives `L = [b,d,e]` as a solution.

Comment: I will try and implement your way, just a guess but would it be [] and [b,c,a,d,e] and I think [d,e].

Comment: Yes, those are the solutions I would expect.

Comment: Ah so my solution removes all occurences of From, To from the result, thanks for your help I'll try your way it does seem to better and bug free! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution you came up with is interesting and it only needs a small adjustment to make it work correctly:

```
% Split a list at a specified index
split(List, Index, Front, Back) :-
    length(Front, Index),
    append(Front, Back, List).

% Get list items inbetween members
inbetween(List, From, To, Result) :-
    nth1(FromI, List, From),
    split(List, FromI, _, List1),
    nth0(ToI, List1, To),
    split(List1, ToI, Result, _).
```

The `split/4` predicate is unchanged from what you have. The `inbetween/4` main predicate I modified a little so that first it finds everything after the `From`, then it *uses that result* and finds everything before the `To` yielding the final result.

```
| ?-  inbetween([a,b,c,a,x,b,e,f], a, b, L).

L = [] ? ;

L = [b,c,a,x] ? ;

L = [x] ? ;

(1 ms) no
```

---

A shorter version, using `append/3` would be:

```
betwixt2(List, A, B, Result) :-
    append(_, [A|T], List),
    append(Result, [B|_], T).
```

---

Another approach which is more recursively based and not using library calls would be:

```
inbetween(List, A, B, Result) :-
    split_left(List, A, R),
    split_right(R, B, Result).

split_left([X|T], X, T).
split_left([_|T], X, R) :- split_left(T, X, R).
split_right([X|_], X, []).
split_right([H|T], X, [H|R]) :- split_right(T, X, R).
```

---

And finally, there's an interesting, concise solution, I hadn't considered when making my comments, using a DCG which is more transparent:

```
betwixt(A, B, M) --> anything, [A], collect(M), [B], anything.

anything --> [].
anything --> [_], anything.

collect([]) --> [].
collect([H|T]) --> [H], collect(T).

inbetween(List, A, B, Result) :- phrase(betwixt(A, B, Result), List).
```

The DCG in this case nicely spells out exactly what's happening, with the same results as above. For brevity, I could also use `collect(_)` in place of `anything` in the first clause, but didn't want to waste the unused argument.

To use a nice notation credited to @false, we can use `...` as a term as shown below:

```
betwixt(A, B, M) --> ..., [A], collect(M), [B], ... .

... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .

collect([]) --> [].
collect([H|T]) --> [H], collect(T).
```

Comment: Only just seen this. Thanks for your great insight into this, it has definitely made me understand it much much more.

Comment: +1 for the DCG version! In addition, you can even omit `anything//0` entirely and use `collect(_)` instead to simply ignore the argument. By the way, a nice way to write `anything//0` is due to @false: `... --> ([] | [_], ... )`. So you can write: `betwixt(A, B, Ls) --> ..., [A], list(Ls), [B], ... .`, assuming you also call collect//1 simply `list//1`, which is a more declarative and meaningful name (usable in all directions).

Comment: @mat In my original I did use `collect(_)` and changed it for some whimsical reason. And, haha, yes actually I was going to use the `...` term that I had also learned from `false`, but I only avoided it so as not to appear to plagiarize his cool idea. :)

Comment: Just use it and mention it is initially due to @false!

Comment: (BTW `anything//0` is also already a much better name, since it does not imply a direction and can be used in the "generate" as well as "parse" and also "check" operational sense, so I can see why you used it instead. Still, @false's `...` is by far the best I think. That's why I also recommend `list//1`.)

Comment: @mat yes, I like `list//1` better than `collect//1` as well, having considered it. I like the `...` because it's so unobtrusive and it draws more attention to the salient portions of the code.